# Retirar loader após a página se carregar totalmente

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um loader customizado que aparece na tela enquanto está carregando. Quando acabo preciso que esse loader desapareça, até ai tudo bem. O problema é que a página ainda está fazendo alguns processos com o jQuery e a div do loader desaparece, dando o efeito que aparentemente carregou, mas na verdade não.

O navegador não aparece carregando, mas por trás ele ainda esta executando alguns processos com o jQuery. Queria que quando realmente carregar tudo, seja links ou códigos ai sim ele usaria o código que tenho abaixo, mas estou usando ele e não está 100% como preciso:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

//... Retiro a class da DIV do nosso Loader

});
```

Comment: Os pedaços que estão a carregar depois vêm por ajax?

Comment: @Sergio sim, algumas coisas vem pelo $.getJSON

Comment: Quantos `$.getJSON` tens? Caso sejam vários podes coloca-los na pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente, você pode usar `window.onload`, mas você pode perceber que os navegadores recentes não acionam `window.onload` quando você usa os botões/histórico para a frente ou para trás.

Algumas pessoas sugerem "coisas" estranhas para contornar este problema, por alguma razão ainda existem pessoas que usam setIntervale e outros hacks estranhos.

- A documentação sugere estritamente:

  `window.onload = function () { alert("Carregou!") }`
- Existem [alternativas](http://prototypejs.org/)

  `Event.observe(window, 'load', function(event) {
      // feito
  });`
- [APIS](https://github.com/ironboy/mongresto/tree/master)

Mas entre `DOMContentLoaded/load` e `document.readyState`, penso que há alguns recursos que garanta que o documento é carregado:

```
`HTMLDocument.prototype.ready = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
            resolve(document);
        } else {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            resolve(document);
        });
                    }
    });
}
document.ready().then(...);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualquer que seja a linguagem, o jQuery vai informar que sua página foi concluída quando o DOM for carregado. Como você executa operações assíncronas pós-carregamento do DOM, sugiro que você coloque o código da retirada do seu loader depois da última ação assíncrona dinâmica, tipo:

```
$.getJSON("[sua-ultima-carga].json", function(data){
    // Sua lógica de carregamento
    // Retira o loader
});
```

Outra possibilidade, já que você tem múltiplos carregamentos assíncronos é utilizar o WHEN para retirar o load após a conclusão de todos:

```
$.when(carregamento1, carregamento2).then(
  function(resultado1, resultado2) {
    // retira o loader depois que os carregamentos 1 e 2 terminarem
  }, 
  function(Erro) {
    // qualquer carregamento que der erro dispara essa function com o resultado do erro onde você deve retirar o loader para tratar o erro
  }
});
```